# Android Studio OTG connection / broadcast reciever (Arduino & Parse)

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, arduino

I am trying to create an application, that takes data from Arduino Sensors and put it into a Parse.com database. My issue, is that I am unable to 'catch' or 'store' the string I desire, in the correct format, in order to pass it onto parse. I am rather new to Android Studio and Arduino.

The method I have used so far, can take the Arduino data and append it to a text view. But after working 2 weeks on this, I can't find a solution. Likely because I do not have deep knowledge.

I used the [guide](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/).

I believe the main snippets are the Broadcast Reciever function. Which is identical to the guide, as my attempts to modify it has failed. The solution might require a whole new structure. I only took this guide as it initially seemed like what I needed.

So far, the text is correctly read into Android, it can be text appended into a text view, but not sequenced / formatted and sent to parseAppend()

**Question 1:** Is this the right approach, to retrieve data and format it into a String of structure "1#2".

**Question 2:** How would approach solving this problem? Where would I store the data and be able to implement a function call to parseAppend(str,d,d);

```
    UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.

        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                data.concat("/n");
                tvAppend(motivationalText, data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    };


    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { //Broadcast Receiver to automatically start and stop the Serial connection.
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
            boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (granted) {
                connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
                if (serialPort != null) {
                    if (serialPort.open()) { //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
                        setUiEnabled(true);
                        serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
                        serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                        serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                        serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                        serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                        serialPort.read(mCallback);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT NOT OPEN");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT IS NULL");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("SERIAL", "PERM NOT GRANTED");
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            onClickStart(scanBtn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
            onClickStop(stopBtn);

        }
    }

    ;
};
```

The function onto Parse takes a String, LNG and LAT. The format can be seen in the test String, consisting of 8 data values. It works like this:

```
private void parseAppend(String text, double LNG, double LAT){

    final String dataString = "1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8";
    //final String dataString = text;

    final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Gas");
    String splitData[] = dataString.split("#");

    testObject.put("UVA", splitData[1]);
    testObject.put("UVB", splitData[2]);
    testObject.put("NO2", splitData[3]);
    testObject.put("CO", splitData[4]);
    testObject.put("O3", splitData[5]);
    testObject.put("DUST", splitData[6]);
    testObject.put("TEMPERATURE", splitData[7]);
    testObject.put("HUMIDITY", splitData[7]);
    testObject.put("LNG", LNG);
    testObject.put("LAT", LAT);
    testObject.put("Test ID", "New Function");

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            testObject.saveInBackground();

            ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
        }

    });

}
```

Really hope if someone could guide me in the right direction!